# URL Rewrite rule in .htaccess for Root directory

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am using this rule to rewrite the link

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*) show_cv.php?email=$1
```

It is working fine like if I write this url with last slash

```
www.mysite.com/letschat_2008@yahoo.com/  ---->  index.php?email=letschat_2008@yahoo.com
```

But when I remove the last slash from the link `www.mysite.com/letschat_2008@yahoo.com/` it shows error 404.

I wish the URL Rewrite rule would work for both with slash and without slash (`/`)

```
www.mysite.com/letschat_2008@yahoo.com/ ----> index.php?email=letschat_2008@yahoo.com
www.mysite.com/letschat_2008@yahoo.com ----> index.php?email=letschat_2008@yahoo.com
```

Answer (score 1):

Your rules are looping, you need to make sure you are rewriting an email address, and add some conditions so that the rule doesn't get applied if it's accessing an existing resource:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\@\.]+)/?$ /show_cv.php?email=$1 [L]
```

Comment: @DEVESH accept the answer so that your question doesn't show up in the list of unanswered questions

Answer (score 0):

You should then be using the following rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/? show_cv.php?email=$1
```

Comment: Well i already use this rule but in show_cv.php i am not getting "letschat_2008@yahoo.com" value in querystring i am getting "show_cv.php" value in querystring.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you note these rules in a .htaccess file, not in the server configuration when looking at your description ?

Rethink if you don-t want to put this into the server configuration. Apart from the usage of .htaccess files being harder to debug using rewrite rules in those files is more complex than in the server configuration. This is documented in mod_rewrites docs.

The reason for the behaviour is the different content of REQUEST_URI in both cases. Have a try checking this directly and you will see the problem. The whole part "letschat_2008@yahoo.com" is simply missing in that variable in case 2 (no "/"). To get this working you must use an additional rewriteCondition (also documented...). Something like these untested lines:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.+)&
RewriteRule - show_cv.php?email=%1
```

(note the '%' instead of a '$' in the last line)

Comment: when i am putting this line RewriteCondition %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.+)& this line i am getting error "Internal Server Error"

Comment: Sorry, as mentioned the lines are untested, I wrote them from memory. You will have to try around a little, but that approach works. It is 'RewriteCond', not 'RewriteCondition'.